# Calling MS .Net Webservices with Ruby

Tags: .net, ruby, web-services

Has anyone done this / have some example code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#use .wsdl file to initialize an RPC driver
driver = SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new('dotnetwebservice.wsdl').create_rpc_driver

#useful debugging call
driver.wiredump_dev = STDERR

#Set the enconding style to ASP.NET
driver.default_encodingstyle = SOAP::EncodingStyle::ASPDotNetHandler::Namespace

#call method defined in .wsdl
result = driver.serviceMethod()
```

For more info: http://dev.ctor.org/soap4r

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Ruby has a built in [wsdl driver](http://harborsparrow.blogspot.com/2007/07/using-rubys-wsdl-driver-to-call.html).

Answer (score 0):

Good starting point in this thread **Ruby SOAP client communication with Microsoft .NET webservice**

[here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.ruby/browse_thread/thread/ef4653f192455323)